# Servlet java.lang.NumberFormatException

Tags: java, servlets

I'm receiving two parameters on the servlet that I need to put as string so that in the `PreparedStatement` I can use `setInt(1, parameter)`.

```
public class rate extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
        Connection con = null;
       //FileItem f1;
        String id = request.getParameter("idbook");
        String opcoes = request.getParameter("voto");
        int idlivro=Integer.parseInt(id);
        int opcao = Integer.parseInt(opcoes);
        String updateString = "Update rating set livros_rate = ? where productId = ?";
        if (idlivro != 0)
     {

          try {
         //connect to DB 
         con = login.ConnectionManager.getConnection();
         pstmt = con.prepareStatement(updateString);
         pstmt.setInt(1, opcao);
         pstmt.setInt(2, idlivro);
         pstmt.executeUpdate();
      }
          catch (Exception e){
      }finally{
             try {
                 pstmt.close();
                 con.close();
             } catch (SQLException ex) {
                 Logger.getLogger(rate.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
             }

          }
     }
}
```

However, it throws the following exception:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:454)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at counter.rate.doPost(rate.java:45)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Edit: I'll put the code of the form that send's the parameters.

```
<div id="templatemo_content_right">
    <div class="templatemo_product_box">
            <h1><%=rs.getString(3)%>  <span>(<%=rs.getString(7)%>)</span></h1>
        <img src="<%=rs.getString(13)%>"/>
            <div class="product_info">
                <p><%=rs.getString(10)%></p>
                   <div><form action="rate"  method="POST">
                            <imput type="hidden" name="idbook" value="<%=rs.getString(1)%>"/>
                            <select name="voto">
                                <option value="0">Did not like</option>
                                <option value="1">Ok</option>
                                <option value="2" selected="selected">Liked</option>
                                <option value="3">Loved!</option>
                            </select>
                            <input type="submit" value="Votar!"/>
                    </form></div>
```

is the form causing the problem?

Comment: What is most likely happening is that you don't have a request parameter called `idbook`. When you try to parse it, it is null and therefore throws `NumberFormatException`.

Comment: Please use a debugger to check if any of the arguments is `null`.

Answer (score 4):

Exception is pretty descriptive, you are trying to parse null as an int. do a null check before you invoke `parseInt()`

```
String id = request.getParameter("idbook");
    String opcoes = request.getParameter("voto");
int idlivro=0;    
if(id!=null)
   idlivro =Integer.parseInt(id);
    int opcao =0;
if(opcoes!=null)
 opcao=Integer.parseInt(opcoes);
```

**OneLiner:**

```
int idlivro  = (id!=null) ? Integer.parseInt(id) : 0;
```

Comment: I often wrap `Integer.parseInt(<string>);` in a `try { ... } catch (NumberFormatException e) { ... }` because an bad string like "moof" will cause a `NumberFormatException`. Often I have a default value or some kind of behavior I want to trigger if the parsing fails.

Comment: @MichaelShopsin **NFE** is an unchecked runtime exception. you don't really need to wrap it around try/catch .. :)

Comment: The real problem is not handling the `null` value parameters, it would be to guide OP why the parameters aren't sent to server side. Also, if one of this parameters is indeed `null`, then OP should return an error message, not use a `0` value (that might return nothing)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza to answer that we need to see the code where OP has set the values in the request :)

Comment: Yes, but I don't see you asking OP for that info either =\

Comment: @PremGenError because **NFE** is a runtime exception I have to use a try catch block if I want to assign a default value on error. In this case the problem seems to be a null pointer, but I've often had to run past **NFE**.

Comment: @MichaelShopsin ahhh, gotcha now. but don't you think suppressing the exception is a bad design ??

Comment: @PremGenError In general suppressing errors is bad, but in this case **NFE** really should be an error return for you to decide not an exception. For example if you want count to default to 0 but allow a parameter to override it: `int count = 0; try { count = Integer.parseInt(str); } catch ( NumberFormatException e ) { count = 0; }`

Answer (score 0):

```
int idlivro=Integer.parseInt(id);
int opcao = Integer.parseInt(opcoes);
```

May be id or opcao is null or have space in it. So you getting  java.lang.NumberFormatException.

Possible cases:

```
id ="";
id = "  123";
id=null;
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you are not getting the parameters you are expecting (as in request.getParameter("idbook"); is null).

Here's a quick test class:

```
public class IntProb {

public static final String SOME_STRING = "888";
public static final String NULL_STRING = null;

public static void main(String[] argv) {

    System.out.println("-------- Testing parseInt ------------");

    System.out.println("converting SOME_STRING: ");
    try{
        int intSomeInt = Integer.parseInt(SOME_STRING);

    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("converting NULL_STRING: ");
    try{
        int intSomeInt = Integer.parseInt(NULL_STRING);

    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("-------- End of parseInt Test ------------");

}

}
```

$ javac IntProb.java 
$ java IntProb

yeilds:

```
-------- Testing parseInt ------------
converting SOME_STRING: 
converting NULL_STRING: 
java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:417)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:499)
at IntProb.main(IntProb.java:20)
-------- End of parseInt Test ------------
```

Trying to pass null into parseInt goes badly.

Comment: Could you please take a look at the form code i added to the original post?

Answer (score 0):

A `NumberFormatException` is thrown to indicate that an application tried to convert a `String` to a numeric type, but failed due to an incorrect format of the parsed `String`.

In your code, the possible offending lines are this ones:

```
int idlivro=Integer.parseInt(id);
int opcao = Integer.parseInt(opcoes);
```

The two of them are parameters, obtained directly from the request:

```
String id = request.getParameter("idbook");
String opcoes = request.getParameter("voto");
```

Please check the format of those parameters (in particular, check if they're not `null` or `"null"`) or, if you have no control over them, catch that `NumberFormatException` with a `try-catch` block:

```
//Code
try {
    //More Code
    int idlivro=Integer.parseInt(id);
    int opcao = Integer.parseInt(opcoes);
    //More Code
} catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
    //Logic that should be executed if the book or the option are invalid.
}
```

Of course, you can also try and catch each individual parse if it suits you. Alternatively (and if you know you're not fetching any `null` parameter) you can use a regular expression to validate the string before trying to parse it (a cleaner approach, IMHO), like this:

```
String id = request.getParameter("idbook");
String opcoes = request.getParameter("voto");
//...
if(Pattern.matches("/^\d+$/", id)) {
    //Safe parse here.
}
```

Build your code the way you need it, but by adding this check before parsing you avoid having to deal with a `NUmberFormatException`.

Answer (score 0):

On line 8 of your form you have a syntax error that could possibly be causing issues with the getRequest

see:<**imput** type="hidden" name="idbook" value="<%=rs.getString(1)%>"/>

***imput***!= **input**