# thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null

Tags: java

I'm a beginner to Java programming and I encounter the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
            at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:454)
            at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:582)
            at ReadWrite.ReaderStudent.Read(ReaderStudent.java:35)
            at ReadWrite.Writer.main(Writer.java:24)
        Java Result: 1
```

And the code:

```
package ReadWrite;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import Student.*;

public class ReaderStudent {
    public Student[] Read() {
        Student[] S;
        S = new Student[10];
        try {
            FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File("d:\\JavaProjects\\JavaLab_04_B\\data.txt"));
            String str, gr;
            String id;
            int id1;
            DataInputStream ids = new DataInputStream(is);
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                str = ids.readLine();
                gr = ids.readLine();
                id = ids.readLine();
                id1 = Integer.valueOf(id).intValue();
                S[i] = new Student(str, gr, id1);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error writing file" + e);
        }
        return S;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is extremely hard to read. If you are a beginner, the first thing you should do is learn proper code formatting practices. I suggest you [start here](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javaguide.html#s4.1-braces).

Comment: Why don't you use `Integer.parseInt()` method to convert a string to integer.

Comment: valueOf: `Returns an Integer object holding the value of the specified String. The argument is interpreted as representing a signed decimal integer, exactly as if the argument were given to the parseInt(java.lang.String) method.` So, same difference.

Comment: @Gowtham as you can see in the stack trace, that's exactly what `valueOf()` does.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Servlet java.lang.NumberFormatException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14961662/servlet-java-lang-numberformatexception) among numerous others.

Comment: try using `Integer.parseInt(String)` instead of `valueof`, and also for id try using `long`

Answer (score 1):

This exception occurs if you try to convert a string to a number, where the string does not actually contain a number.

Example:

`Integer.valueOf("10").intValue();` works, but `Integer.valueOf("abcd").intValue()` throws out the `NumberFormatException`.

Check your input file and make sure you're actually having a number there.

Line by Line debugger would be very useful here. Also use the good old `System.out.println` to see the value in `id`.

Answer (score 0):

That exception means that when you are executing this line of code

> id1 = Integer.valueOf(id).intValue();

the value you are trying to convert into an integer (`id`), isn't a number.

You need to double check your input file's format.